# Composição com interfaces fluentes

Tags: c#

Estou tentando fazer uma classe utilizando composição, métodos fluentes e estou tendo alguns problemas.

Gostaria de acessar uma propriedade de um método compositivo através de interfaces fluentes mas não consigo implementar o método abstrato.

O caso é o seguinte:

```
// Classe base para composição
public abstract class Foo
{
    // Propriedade base
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    // Método base para retorno da classe (usado com interfaces fluentes)
    public abstract Foo GetData();
}

// Classe que compoe Foo
public class Bar : Foo
{
    // Propriedade particular de Bar
    public string Param2 { get; set; }

    // Método para retorno da própria classe (usado com interfaces fluentes)
    // Aqui eu não consigo criar o método
    public override Bar GetData()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

// Classe que utiliza
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        // Acesso à propriedade particular da classe compositiva
        var newBar = new Bar().GetData().Param2;
    }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer isso?

Comment: Acho que tipo do retorno do método da classe compositivo deve ser o objeto pai (`public override Foo GetData()`).

Comment: Você não pode declarar este método como override: `public override Bar GetData()` porque ele não existe em nenhuma classe acima na hierarquia (não existe na classe pai). O método na classe pai retorna `Foo` e não `Bar`.

Comment: O problema de eu voltar o mesmo objeto do pai (Foo) no GetData() é que com ele eu não terei acesso a propriedade Param2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o generic na classe base, utilizar o "T" como retorno do "GetData", e ao herdar dessa classe passar o tipo que deseja utilizar no método "GetData":

```
// Classe base para composição
public abstract class Foo<T>
{
    // Propriedade base
    public string Param1 { get; set; }

    // Método base para retorno da classe (usado com interfaces fluentes)
    public abstract T GetData();
}

// Classe que compoe Foo
public class Bar : Foo<Bar>
{
    // Propriedade particular de Bar
    public string Param2 { get; set; }

    // Método para retorno da própria classe (usado com interfaces fluentes)
    // Aqui eu não consigo criar o método
    public override Bar GetData()
    {
        return this;
    }
}

// Classe que utiliza
public class Test
{
    public Test()
    {
        // Acesso à propriedade particular da classe compositiva
        var newBar = new Bar().GetData().Param2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esse código não vai compilar. Ele tem o mesmo problema do código do formulador da pergunta: `public override Bar GetData()` - não há método correspondente para ser sobrescrito.

Comment: Eu testei, compilou e funcionou. Como você define o tipo T que será utilizado na herança da classe, haverá sim um método para dar overrite, já que na classe base você define `public abstract T GetData();`

Comment: Funcionou, valeu ae Michel!

Comment: Hmm Ok. Eu declararia o método na classe filha com a mesma assinatura. Mas não creio de qualquer modo que isso tornaria esse código mais interessante.

Comment: Eu também usaria `T`. Tenho minhas dúvidas se funcionaria em qualquer situação. Mas não estou com tempo para testar isto.